# Android - Parse a part of JSON file from server

Tags: java, android, json, database

I work on a social media app with JSON file as a database. The problem is how can I parse ONLY a specific part (like a specific user information) without parsing the whole JSON database into the device?

Comment: You still have to parse the JSON to locate the information you need, but you don't have to load the uninteresting information into memory if you use a **streaming** JSON parser. --- However, every time you need to look something up, you have to parse from the beginning again, so it'll be slow when the JSON file grows in size. You might want to re-think using a JSON file as a database.

Comment: Doesn't the slowing effect happen in every database? @Andreas

Comment: No, because databases have indexes for faster lookup.

Comment: Is parsing sql using json good enough? @Andreas

Comment: No idea what you mean by "parsing sql using json".

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/json-parsing-in-android/ @Andreas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223597/discussion-between-shak1234-and-andreas).